# C# build generates a lot build-in dll files

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a simple .NET 4.6.1 console application (not .NET core), as below
[image]

References are

[image]

The problem is, once compiled, it generates a hefty lot of dlls that are supposed to be build-in dlls. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Please add the code itself to your question instead of the screenshot of it.

Comment: Are you referencing any NuGet package?

Comment: close visual studio.
delete bin and obj folder in the solution.
open visual studio again.
rebuild solution. This usually solves it for me.

Comment: What are you actually referencing from your project? You might actually need these, but it's not really possible to say with the information given. That is an awful lot of dlls.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes I use some nuget packages. I personally installed Google GRPC and OpenCV, they may themselves add some dependencies. I add it to the question above. Could this be caused one of the packages?

Comment: If a package targets .Net Standard, yes.  You would get all of those dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left a big clue in the screenshot.
[image: netstandard]

They're recommending that libraries target .NET standard.
There's a good discussion at:

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/146

> Libraries should generally target .NET Standard as this ensures that
>   they can be consumed by any app. There will be circumstances where you
>   need to access .NET Core specific APIs, either because the API is new
>   and not implemented anywhere else, or the concept is .NET Core only.
>   That's why I believe we should make it easy to retarget between .NET
>   Standard and .NET Core so that developers never have to fear being
>   "locked in". Start with NET Standard and retarget if necessary &
>   revert back once a new version of the standard is available that has
>   all the APIs you need.

So gRPC now works with .NET Standard.

If you don't want to opt-in, you could build the particular library targeting the .NET Framework.

Comment: Will update if there's a better resolution like an assembly redirect.

Comment: Welp, assembly binding with .NET Standard is still rough.